# How to filter HTML Table - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input box (search box) to filter my html table. My query is able to filter the table alright but when i clear the search box it does not bring back the already existing data

For instance if i have

```
MacBook 
Acer
```

and i search for M

it displays `MacBook` which is fine

but when i clear the `M` from the search box,  the table still looks like

```
 MacBook
```

instead of

```
 MacBook 
    Acer
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
        var doneTypingInterval = 100;  //time in ms (5 seconds)

        $("#query").on('keyup', function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            if ($('#query').val()) {
                typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
            }
        });
    });

    function doneTyping() {
        var key = $('#query').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'search/?query='+key,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () {
               // $("#table").slideUp('fast');

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#table").slideDown('fast');

                     var table = $("#table tbody");

                      table.html("");
                        $.each(data, function(idx, elem){
                            table.append(

                                //appending rows here

                            );

                        });




                }            

            });


}
</script>
```

Comment: you are looking to return a result only if the input has a val. If it is empty you will never invoke the ajax to return results

Comment: @LelioFaieta, how do i get this fixed please? I am new to Javascript

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
$("#query").on('keyup', function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if ($('#query').val()) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });
```

is binded to a keyup event (ok) but will look if $('#query') has a value:

```
if ($('#query').val()) {
```

If you empty the input field this condition will be false.

Simply remove the if condition and this will work.

```
$("#query").on('keyup', function () {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});
```